# DCPromo Semaphore Timeout

Tags: windows-server-2016, timeout, dcpromo

I am trying to Promote a new server to an existing domain using server 2016 but I keep getting an error message stating " The wizard cannot access the list of domains in the forest. The error is: The semaphore timeout period has expired."

Both machines are running windows server 2016. Netlogon and rpc are running on DC1. The new server is static, registered in the dns, pings, firewall/antivirus disabled, and is joined to the domain. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this over WiFi?
Have you tested for a stable link? Generally you get this error when you're copying large files and the connection craps out. Bad NIC/NIC drivers/hardware in general?

Comment: I appreciate your response but No, I am not using wifi and it is stable. I'm assuming I'm copying active directory. I do not think its a bad nic because I created a vm on a different server and ended up with the same error.

Comment: I'd probably need way more information than I could get here via messaging as far as the network configuration. Try turning IPv6 off on the active NIC on one or both of the systems and see if it goes through. If so, you may need to configure that or make changes to your firewall. This is a stab, but I've seen this type of thing a LOT lately with 2016/2019/10.